# Word for "clique member"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word meaning "clique member." Since "clique" is pejorative, this term or inflection would be pejorative as well, likely used by outsiders though not necessarily.

I've checked [Wiktionary for clique](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clique#English).
My best attempts:

- Clique Member - I find it dry and cumbersome, though "member" is reliable for this type of inflection.
- [Cliquemate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cliquemate) - This is pretty good.
- [Cliquey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cliquey#English) - It's adjective but I might use as nonstandard noun, with -ys as the plural. It sounds right to me, regardless of existence of adjective. Has anyone heard this usage as countable noun? When adjectives are used as noun ("the elderly") I believe those are uncountable nouns. I never hear "the elderlys (-ies)". [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/adjectives-used-as-nouns) says adjective as noun is preceded with "the". There's words that double as adjective and countable noun but I consider that a special case, eg "savage(s)".
- Cliquer - Clique is verb, eg "clique up". One who cliques. I can't find this -er usage in web search.
- Cliquey ___ [element, person] - This is my second favorite solution after Cliquey (as noun).

My example sentence is

> This place is overrun by ____ [cliqueys]!

I'm in USA but I don't mind British-oriented answers.

Comment: Does it have to have the word 'clique' in it? Or can it just mean the same thing? And who'd be saying it? Is it the member describing themself? Is it somebody else saying, "Oh, [x] is a _______"?

Comment: ***insiders, in-crowd, inner circle.*** Or just ***elitists***, for many types of clique.

Comment: Why not use "cliquemate"?

Comment: I meant to put "word or expression for clique member". (It's ok how it is.) It should use the word "clique" (including inflections) since there's unique connotation. I'm picturing a pejorative term used by outsider since "clique" is pejorative. "In-crowd" and "inner circle" are synonyms for clique, not members there of. I want countable noun; I feel the question conveys that so I'll leave as is.

Comment: An easy work-around could be "This place is cliquey!"

Comment: I suggest you look at what sort of clique. If it's fashionable schoolgirls, use a word meaning that; for elitist rich people, there may be another word; for people who're bullies or cruelly exclusionary, use a term for that. The thing about a clique member is that there's no way of recognising one on their own, only when they're in a clique.

Comment: In your example sentence, you could just say "This place is overrun by cliques." Can you provide an example where that wouldn't work?

Comment: **This place is overrun by a clique** - that's a simple expression, that refers to all the members as a collective.

Comment: My own research seems to have covered all solutions. There's a reason I framed the question like this. The word should apply to individuals to describe their character. You may not know if it's one clique or many, how its organized, or who's with whom. Words like cliquemate or teammate are used relationally. "They're cliqueys" and "They're cliquemates" are different. The latter is explicitly tying them together. Your comments aren't in vain and may help someone else.

Comment: Why not "This place is overrun by cliques"? A clique member is not really anything without other members of their clique, singling them out as individual members downplays the cohesion that defines the clique in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Clique seems to have inherited its negative connotation through the exclusion of others.

> a narrow exclusive circle or group of persons

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clique#:%7E:text=%3A%20a%20narrow%20exclusive%20circle%20or,common%20interests%2C%20views%2C%20or%20purposes)

One synonym is *ostraciser*:

> one that ostracizes

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostracizer)

which is one who

> ... exclude[s] from a group by common consent

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostracize)

Although not a common word, nor the best reference, [ngram shows consistent usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ostracizer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: You can be ostracized by being excommunicated from a religion, but I don't think anyone would consider the religion to be a clique.

Comment: Why does one preclude the other? One can drive a truck. "One can drive a car, but I don't think anyone would consider the car to be a truck." Sure. Anyway, one can drive a car.

Comment: "What do you call a person who drives a truck?" If you answer "driver", it's technically true, but not specific to trucks so not a helpful answer.

Comment: @Barmar Question is still open if you feel there is something more precise to contribute. If there isn't something more appropriate than "driver" what would you recommend?

Comment: "truck driver" would be the answer to that question. My point is that if you said "Joe is an ostracizer", that wouldn't imply that they're a clique member.

Comment: I don't have an answer to the qustion, I don't think there's anything better than "clique member"